# Error in ARM template function in Release-Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-rm-template

I have an issue with a ARM template in which I replace a certain part with a template function. This happens during the execution of the release pipeline. The ARM template is installed by a Azure Powershell Script which I added to the release pipeline.

Here is the relevant part throwing the error:

```
"parameters": {
    "connections_office365_externalid": {
        "defaultValue": "[concat(resourceGroup().id,'/providers')]/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "connections_sql_externalid": {
        "defaultValue": "[concat(resourceGroup().id, '/providers')]/Microsoft.Web/connections/sql25",
        "type": "String"
    }
},
```

When it comes to the deployment of the ARM template I get the following error:

```
> Status Message: Property id '[concat(resourceGroup().id,
> '/providers')]/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365' at path
> 'properties.parameters.$connections.value.office365.connectionId' is
> invalid. Expect fully qualified resource Id that start with
> '/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}' or
> '/providers/{resourceProviderNamespace}/'.
> (Code:LinkedInvalidPropertyId)
```

It seems that the part with the template function is not executed because the function is not translated into the appropriate value.Does anybody know what could be the issue that this template function is not executed on runtime of the release pipeline?`

UPDATE:

This is how the DefaultValue Part is replaced prior deployment:

I replace a particular part of the string (regex) to have it dynamic

```
(Get-Content $file.FullName -Raw) -replace "\/subscriptions\/(.*?)\/resourceGroups\/customerPrefix(.*?)\/providers","[concat(resourceGroup().id, '/providers')]" | Set-Content $file.FullName
```

Comment: Could you try e.g. `"defaultValue": "[concat(resourceGroup().id,'/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365')]"`

Comment: Hi juunas. I had to add more detail on how I create the relevant string. forgot do mention that I replace a particular (static) part of the DefaultValue to finally have the correct subscription and ressourcegroup etc. So therefore I cannot apply your suggestion above

Comment: Why not use a parameter for the dynamic part? Running a regex replace on a template seems awfully hacky.

Comment: Good question. Could you please explain a bit more detailed what you mean for using a parameter? What I found so far is that if you want to put together a string for example by using a template function the whole content must be handled within a template function. so i.e.

[templateFunction]/xyz

will not work. Instead ist should be [templateFunction/xyz]. Otherwise the template validation fails

Comment: I mean just ARM parameters: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-syntax#parameters. Not sure if it'll work with default values in the parameters you already have though. Might need to move some of that to variables.

Comment: Ahh ok, now I see. Thank you very much for the hint, I'll check :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change your replacing script a little bit to make it work. See below:

I have tested and found the expression `[concat(resourceGroup().id,'/providers')]/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365` cannot be evaluated in the template.

The correct expression should be like below:

`"defaultValue": "[concat(resourceGroup().id, '/providers', '/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365')]"`

Since you want to replace a particular part of the string (regex) to have it dynamic. You can change your replacing script like:

```
(Get-Content $file.FullName -Raw) -replace "\/subscriptions\/(.*?)\/resourceGroups\/(.*?)\/providers(\/.*)`"",'[concat(resourceGroup().id, ''/providers'', ''$3'')]"' | Set-Content $file.FullName
```

Above script will replace relevant string to be like this `"[concat(resourceGroup().id, '/providers', '/Microsoft.Web/connections/sql25')]"`,

Answer (score 2):

If you are setting up Connections through ARM templates for Logic Apps, go ahad and use this piece:

```
"office365_1": {
                "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', parameters('logicAppLocation'), '/managedApis/', 'office365')]",
                "connectionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('office365_1_Connection_Name'))]",
                "connectionName": "[parameters('office365_1_Connection_Name')]"
              }
```